# How to perform search in Node.js MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to perform search on my list in node js  and my code below is subjected to that,

```
 exports.searchlistbyfirstname = function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params;
  var record= db.collection('profile');
  record.find( { $text: { $search: params.id} }, (err, result) => {
   if (err){ return console.log(err)
    }
      if(result){
            response = {status:'success',data:result};
        } else{
            response = {status:'fail'};
        }
      res.send(response);
  });

};
```

I am trying to search `firstname` and I am sure I got wrong.

can anyone please help me

Comment: Where are you firstname query?

Comment: There i am confused,params.id has my firstname value and how should i write the query for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `query` to get your `firstname`

```
record.find({
  firstname: {
    $regex: params.id
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  if (result) {
    response = {
      status: 'success',
      data: result
    };
  } else {
    response = {
      status: 'fail'
    };
  }
  res.send(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you abdulbarik,it worked fine and what is  $regex used for?

Comment: It provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries.See the doc    https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 1):

To perform text search ensure first you have created text index for search field.

like:

```
db.collection('profile').createIndex( { firstName: "text" } );
```

then you can perform text search on that filed(s).

```
// params.id should be like "shaishab"
// but better to use req.query.firstName instead of req.params.id
// and you should change your route for that
record.find({$text: {$search: params.id}}, (err, result) => { 
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(400).send({status: 'fail', error: err});
  }
  if (result) {
    response = {status: 'success', data: result};
  } else {
    response = {status: 'fail'};
  }
  res.send(response);
});
```

**Or** without create text index you can search firstName by using `$regex` operator

```
record.find({firstName: { $regex: req.params.id, $options: 'i' } }, (err, result) => { 
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).send({status: 'fail', error: err});
      }
      if (result) {
        response = {status: 'success', data: result};
      } else {
        response = {status: 'fail'};
      }
      res.send(response);
    });
```